# Pandas - KeyError on merge

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes. I'm using the Jupyter notebook and pandas dataframes. My two dfs look like this:

```
gbdf.dtypes:
product_name            object
Quantity               float64
Product_id               int64
product_group1           int64
product_group1_name     object
product_group2           int64
product_group2_name     object
packing_unit            object
packing_amount           int64
dtype: object


trns.dtypes:
Store_id           int64
Date              object
Price              int64
Net price          int64
Purchase price     int64
Hour               int64
product_id         int64
Quantity           int64
dtype: object
```

Yet, when I try to run

```
gbdfprice = gbdf.merge(gbdf, trns, left_on = 'Product_id', right_on = 'product_id')
```

I get

```
KeyError: 'product_id'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `gbdf.merge(` expects the other dataframe (`trns`) as the first argument. You are passing the same dataframe that you call the merge function on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you have used (that accepts left and right `DataFrame` arguments) is the method associated with the pandas top-level module, however you have actually used the method associated with a `DataFrame` object which accepts only the right argument.

```
import pandas as pd

left = DataFrame(...)
right = DataFrame(...)

#Method you have used
combined = left.merge(right, [options...])
#Method you have taken argument list from
combined = pd.merge(left, right, [options...])
```

From what I can see in the source, `left.merge(right...)` just imports the other `merge` method and runs `merge(self,right,...)`.

So, as @ayhan points out, to fix just remove `gbdf` from the argument list, or you could also replace the `gbdf.merge` call with `pd.merge` and leave the argument list the same.